# style.xml for android ActionBar

Tags: android

i made a styl.xml and the needed .png files for my androidActionBar.
here is the style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_selectable_background_example</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>


    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background_textured_example</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_background_textured_example</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>   
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/ab_selectable_background_example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_spinner_background_ab_example</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/ab_selectable_background_example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ab_progress_horizontal_example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_default_example</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

now if i go to my androidManifest and change the

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

into:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Example"
```

my app crashes right from the start :S is it possible that i somehow need a AppCompat theme because i use

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

im not sure about that. If i do how could i fix it since i want to give my ActionBar a different color and a height attribute.

or should i remove the ActionBar and use the new Toolbar. Im not sure if i can use that though since its from the new Material Design and is only for Lolipop and higher right?

thx for the help

Comment: Add crash logs in the question.

Comment: What's your logcat output says?

Comment: i´ve treid to use the custom theme only in the certain activity and then it crshes with this:java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: "is it possible that i somehow need a AppCompat theme" : yes. It is mentioned in the documentation of ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [this](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100).

Or read the tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your THeme declaration with below one.

Replace this

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

With this

```
 <style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

you might ned to add Android Support library v7 in your project.

Comment: i did that ty. Now i have no Errors anymore but it doesnt apply the theme :S i´ve all drawables etc.. is my xml file ok or i need to change there smth too?

Comment: use this link to generate drawables or action bar customization. Use google chrome for this.
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 0):

Replace every **Holo** with **AppCompat**. I mean in every line where ever you find **Holo** replace it with **AppCompat**